# AI Music Generator Plays the Same Note Over and Over

Tags: python, machine-learning, torch, midi

I'm making an AI Music generator, and when I run the script, it outputs a .MID file. When I play the file on [Midiano](https://midiano.com/), I here a few notes in a row(e.g. E then F then G) and then it moves down a few octaves, and plays a few more notes, before finally repeating the same note for the remainder of the song. Here is my code:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pretty_midi
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

# Function to load MIDI files and convert them to a list of note sequences
def load_midi_files(folder):
    note_sequences = []
    for file in glob.glob(folder + "/*.mid"):
        midi_data = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI(file)
        note_sequence = []
        for instrument in midi_data.instruments:
            for note in instrument.notes:
                note_sequence.append(note.pitch)
        note_sequences.append(note_sequence)
    return note_sequences

# Function to preprocess the note sequences and create input-output pairs
def create_data(note_sequences, sequence_length):
    X = []
    y = []
    for note_sequence in note_sequences:
        for i in range(len(note_sequence) - sequence_length):
            input_sequence = note_sequence[i:i+sequence_length]
            output_sequence = note_sequence[i+sequence_length]
            X.append(input_sequence)
            y.append(output_sequence)
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    return X, y

# Function to generate new music
def generate_music(model, seed_sequence, length):
    generated_sequence = list(seed_sequence)
    for _ in range(length):
        input_sequence = torch.tensor([generated_sequence[-sequence_length:]], dtype=torch.float32)
        input_sequence = input_sequence.unsqueeze(0)  # Add an extra dimension for the batch size
        input_sequence = input_sequence.permute(0, 2, 1)  # Permute the dimensions to match the expected shape
        predicted_note = model(input_sequence)
        generated_sequence.append(predicted_note.item())
    return generated_sequence


# Set the folder containing the input MIDI files
input_folder = "/home/user/Python/AIMusic/MIDIs"

# Set the length of the input sequences
sequence_length = 32

# Load the MIDI files and create the input-output pairs
note_sequences = load_midi_files(input_folder)
X, y = create_data(note_sequences, sequence_length)

# Normalize the input data
X = X / float(max(np.max(X), np.max(y)))

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32)

# Define the model architecture
class MusicGenerator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(MusicGenerator, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        output, _ = self.lstm(x)
        output = self.fc(output[:, -1, :])
        return output

input_size = 1
hidden_size = 256
output_size = 1
model = MusicGenerator(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train the model
num_epochs = 15
batch_size = 128
num_batches = len(X) // batch_size
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in range(num_batches):
        start_idx = batch * batch_size
        end_idx = start_idx + batch_size
        inputs = X[start_idx:end_idx]
        targets = y[start_idx:end_idx]
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs.unsqueeze(2))
        loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

# Set the seed sequence for generating new music
seed_sequence = [60, 62, 64, 65]

# Generate new music
generated_music = generate_music(model, seed_sequence, length=100)

# Convert the generated music to a MIDI file
output_midi = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI()
output_instrument = pretty_midi.Instrument(program=0)
current_time = 0
note_duration = 0.5  # Adjust this value to control the duration of each note

for note in generated_music:
    output_note = pretty_midi.Note(
        velocity=100,
        pitch=int(note),
        start=current_time,
        end=current_time + note_duration
    )
    output_instrument.notes.append(output_note)
    current_time += note_duration

output_midi.instruments.append(output_instrument)
output_midi.write("output.mid")
```

I am training the model on 4 MIDI files that are not too complex. I am doing this because when training the model on about 15 MIDIs that were complex, it got worse not better(in terms of loss). Here is an example output from running the script:

```
Epoch: 1, Loss: 1538.447265625 
Epoch: 2, Loss: 621.125244140625 
Epoch: 3, Loss: 399.3226013183594 
Epoch: 4, Loss: 348.5968017578125 
Epoch: 5, Loss: 337.2205810546875 
Epoch: 6, Loss: 334.2421875 
Epoch: 7, Loss: 333.15252685546875
Epoch: 8, Loss: 332.69378662109375
Epoch: 9, Loss: 332.4940185546875
Epoch: 10, Loss: 332.3995361328125
Epoch: 11, Loss: 332.355712890625
Epoch: 12, Loss: 332.33477783203125
Epoch: 13, Loss: 332.3233947753906
Epoch: 14, Loss: 332.3178405761719
Epoch: 15, Loss: 332.3150939941406
```

I tried changing the batch_size and sequence length, but I'm not sue what values would be optimal.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you interpret loss `332.31`? Is that good or bad? I don't know anything about your training data other than it sounds like there is too little of it. You may have run into a case of overfitting: repeating the same notes over and over again may be just a local optimum. It's hard to say without knowing your goal.